# How to update image_path in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm want to delete existing images and update with new images using in laravel using this  method

```
if($request->hasFile('images')) {    
            $listingImages = $listing->images;
            foreach($listingImages as $listingImage) {
                $img_path = 'images/listing/'.$listing->id;
                if(File::exists($img_path)) {
                    File::deleteDirectory($img_path);
                    $listingImage->delete();
                }
                foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
                    $listingImage = new ListingImage;
                    $imageName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

                    $listingImage->listing_id = $listing->id;
                    $listingImage->image_path = 'images/listing/'.$listing->id."/".$imageName;
                    $listingImage->save();
                    $image->move(public_path('images/listing/'.$listing->id),$imageName);
                } 
            }
        }
```

so far i can delete the previous directory and update new image path on the database.
but each time i run the edit listing, I get a **Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException
The file "8 (2).jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.** and the old listingImages isn't been deleted on my database.
what proper way can i use to achieve updating multiple listing images?

Answer (score 0):

try `Storage::delete()` function ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#deleting-files

and don't delete `Directory` i think in future u can need to image in that `Directory`

```php
  if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
            $listingImages = $listing->images;

            foreach ($listingImages as $listingImage) {
                foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {

                    $oldImage = $listingImage->image_path;
                    $listingImage = new ListingImage;
                    $imageName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $listingImage->listing_id = $listing->id;
                    $listingImage->image_path = 'images/listing/' . $listing->id . "/" . $imageName;
                    $listingImage->save();
                    $image->move(public_path('images/listing/' . $listing->id), $imageName);

                    \Storage::delete($oldImage); // it will not work if u r not setup `Storage` 
                    //then u can use unlink 
                     unlink(public_path().'/'.$oldImage); //

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: nothing changes, I'm still having the same result. **The file "4.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.**

Comment: please how can i enable the debugger

Comment: in `.env`  put `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: then check `laravel.log` file in storage folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220421/discussion-between-toby-nwude-and-kamlesh-paul).